# Laravel Sum each section using foreach

Tags: laravel-5, foreach, eloquent, sum, laravel-blade

I have below table with data.

```
    ID - CLASS - CATEGORY - AMOUNT
    --------------------------------
     1    I       A          5000
     2    I       B          6000
     3    I       C          7000
     4    V       A          9000
     5    V       B          12000
```

now I want to sum the amount classwise in blade.php using foreach loop. like class I total is 18000, class V 21000 etc..

Controller Function:

```
   $viewRecords = YearlyFees::Where('registration_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('yearly_fees_setup',
        ['viewRecords' => $viewRecords]);
```

Blade.php

```
     @foreach($viewRecords as $record)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$record->Standard->class}}</td>

                    <td>
                        {{$record->Category->category}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$record->amount}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> ?????? TOTAL of each class </td></tr>
            @endforeach
```

Result:

```
Class   Category          Amount
I       School Fees       5000
I       Tution Fees       6000
I       Library Fees      7000
                         **I WANT TOTAL HERE**
V       School Fees       9000
V       Tution Fees       12000
                         **I WANT TOTAL HERE**
```

Please help

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a variable (or two) inside the for loop do conditionally echo out the total.

```
@php
$total = 0;
$category = null;
@endphp
@foreach(...)
    @php
    $total += $record->amount;
    @endphp
    @if ($category != $record->category)
        {{ $total }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: i have a different category which are repeating classwise

Comment: i need some class wise